# Image color changed after resizing in jimp

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing

Image color changed after resizing image using `jimp`

```
const Jimp = require('jimp')

async function main() {
   const image = await Jimp.read('https://awsstage-test.s3.amazonaws.com/26836/1568007235421.jpg')
   image.quality(60).scale(0.4).write('scale1.png')
}
main()
```

Comment: It's because you are using JPG instead of PNG

Comment: can you post both the pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jimp` **DOES NOT** support **CMYK** color space. Only RGB for JPEG files because the internal library `jpeg-js` only supprt RGB and RGBA.

But the color space of your file is CMYK(I used exiftool to confirm):

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.65
File Name                       : 1568007235421.jpg
XMP Toolkit                     : Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c145 79.163499, 2018/08/13-16:40:22
Format                          : image/jpeg
Title                           : Print
Metadata Date                   : 2019:09:02 20:29:02+01:00
Modify Date                     : 2019:09:02 19:29:04Z
Create Date                     : 2019:09:02 20:29:02+01:00
Creator Tool                    : Adobe Illustrator CC 23.0 (Macintosh)
Startup Profile                 : Print
Producer                        : Adobe PDF library 10.01
Profile CMM Type                : Adobe Systems Inc.
Profile Version                 : 2.1.0
Profile Class                   : Output Device Profile
**Color Space Data                : CMYK**
Profile Connection Space        : Lab
```

I converted the image using this online site: https://www.cmyk2rgb.com/ and used the image as input and it worked as expected.